# Lack of await warning in async method that has await in a lambda

Tags: c#, async-await

Either Visual Studio is confused, or I am (probably me).

If I have

```cs
public async Task<Response> DoSomething()
{
    //stuff
    listOfStuff.ForEach(async s => await _repo.DoThing(s));
    return new Response(listOfStuff.Count);
}
```

It complains that

> This async method lacks 'await' ...

However if I change my method to

```cs
public async Task<Response> DoSomething()
{
    //stuff
    foreach (var s in listOfStuff)
    {
        await _repo.DoThing(s);
    }
    return new Response(listOfStuff.Count);
}
```

Then it is perfectly happy and the warning goes away.

So twofold question, is the warning correct and if it is, what is the reasoning for the difference? I'm under the impression that the two methods are intrinsically the same, if the warning is correct, then I must assume that my impression is wrong.

Comment: In the first version the `await` is part of that lambda function not the enclosing `DoSomething`, therefore `DoSomething` lacks an `await`

Comment: @JSteward can you elaborate on that? The one in the loop is contained in a loop, that sounds very similar to being enclosed in a lambda. Also, if `listOfStuff` is empty then neither will actually run and no `await` is ever touched.

Comment: `DoSomething` is a function, the lambda function is... a function. In the first version only the lambda has an `await`. It doesn't matter if `listOfStuff` may or may not be empty `DoSomething`, in the second version, has an `await`.

Comment: Ok, is there an actual functional difference between the two? At the core level of iterating through a list and calling a method on each item in the list, is there an actual difference between the two implementations?

Comment: [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/e0bf122d0e52a42688b92bb4be2cfd66ca3c2f07/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#L545) takes an `Action<T>` not a `Func<T, Task>`, so when you send an async function to it you've created an `async void` method that is unawaitable.

Comment: @JSteward can you flesh all that out into a proper answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version, the `DoSomething` function lacks an `await` operator. The only `await` is within the async void lambda passed to the `ForEach` method. In the second version the `DoSomething` function has an `await` as part of the actual body of the function and thus you get no warning. It doesn't matter if the `listOfStuff` may or may not be empty, the condition that the method needs an `await` is satisfied.

Now the functional difference may not be immediatly clear but it is critical. As stated the first version uses an async void method. That is un-awaitable and the method will therefore continue before the async operation completes as you can see with this test:

```
[Test]
public void DoSomething()
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
    list.ForEach(async x => await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
}
```

Result `6ms`, not the 10 seconds we'd expect. The second version of your code is a properly awaitable `async Task`:

```
[Test]
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
    foreach(var x in list)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
}
```

And we see the result is: `10032ms` right within expectations.

Comment: The addition of the test case really helps clarify. I'm very surprised by the functional difference of `.ForEach()` vs `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

If we replace the lambda with a local function, things may become clearer:

```
public async Task<Response> DoSomething()
{
    //stuff
    listOfStuff.ForEach(ProcessStuffAsync);
    return new Response(listOfStuff.Count);

    async Task ProcessStuffAsync(Stuff s) // local function
    {
        await _repo.DoThing(s);
    }
}
```

The `DoSomething` method returns a `Task`, but it is not really asynchronous because it lacks an `await`. So the `Task` returned will be in a completed state. All code inside `DoSomething` (excluding the code inside the local function) will run synchronously.

The local function `ProcessStuffAsync` is trully asynchronous, and will return one `Task` each time is called. These tasks are neither awaited nor stored somewhere inside the `DoSomething` method, so they are fire-and-forget tasks. Nobody knows what's gonna happen to them.

---

**Update:** The code above doesn't compile because [`List.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach) cannot accept the `ProcessStuffAsync` local function as argument. The compiler complains that it has wrong return type. To make the code compile, the local function must return `void`. But [async void](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) functions are a can of worms by themselves.